# How Azure AD scopes, permissions and tokens work with exposing API?

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-active-directory, access-token

I am currently working on React Native app that uses Azure as backend and I am having trouble to call API in azure LogicApp that requires custom scope. We have this scope in "AppRegistration/Expose an API". ([screenshot-expose an API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piZLp.png))

In the mobile app I ask for scopes *"openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access"*. I need to call Microsoft Graph for user information. This is no problem as we added required permissions (User.ReadWrite.All) into AppRegistration/permissions.

- I can call what I need
- I get refresh token which I need

But I cannot call our API due to invalid token (http 401).

So the question is, **how to properly setup permissions and scopes in the AppRegistration?**

What I have tried:

- adding required scope to mobile application

  - this cause my other scopes to "disappear". So in my decoded token i can see only this scope.
  - Additionaly I don't receive valid refresh token and I cannot call Microsoft Graph with access token I get.
- not adding scope to the mobile app but adding permission to custom API into permissions. ([screenshot-permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrTzt.png))

  - this way I still couldnt call custom API

I really don't understand why the scopes I ask from mobile app are ignored and why permissions from AppRegistration are not working either when I ask for the custom scope from "Expose an API".

Comment: `why permissions from AppRegistration are not working either when I ask for the custom scope from "Expose an API"` ---- that may some mistake in your code. `why the scopes I ask from mobile app are ignored` ---- generate access token require us to set the scope, we can only set one kind of api scope one time, for example, you want the token to have permission to call graph api, then you can't add `api://app_id/xxxx` in your scope. if you want to get refresh token as well when generating access token, you need to add `offline_access` in the scope

Comment: I see, so one API at a time. But I need to call MsGraph to get user information.
How do I do that? should I keep both tokens for both APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tiny Wang said, i have to obtain 2 pairs of tokens. One for each API resource.